# State management library for React with direct read and mutate capabilities?

Tags: reactjs, valtio

For my current personal project Valtio is *almost* the perfect state management library for React. https://github.com/pmndrs/valtio

The benefits for me are:

- I can use the state object without worrying about unnecessary re-renders. If the value of `foo` changes `App` doesn't care.
- I can mutate state directly. In my real application I have deeply nested state.

```
import React from 'react'
import {proxy, useSnapshot} from 'valtio';
const state = proxy({ count: 0, foo: 'bar' })

export default function App() {
  const snap = useSnapshot(state);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Number: {snap.count}</h2>
      <button onClick={()=>state.count++}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The only thing about the API I would wish to change is that you need a different object for listening to and updating state. Is there any state management library where you can use a single object for both? My perfect API would be something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import {proxy} from 'some-library';
const state = proxy({ count: 0, foo: 'bar' })

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Number: {state.count}</h2>
      <button onClick={()=>state.count++}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or having to use a hook (or whatever), but the same hook for reading and writing would also be cool:

```
import React from 'react'
import {proxy, useSnapshot} from 'some-library';
const state = proxy({ count: 0, foo: 'bar' })

export default function App() {
  const snap = useSnapshot(state);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Number: {snap.count}</h2>
      <button onClick={()=>snap.count++}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there a library with this is a similar developer experience?